# What is the solution for Chikungunya?

Tags: effectiveness, disease, cure, mosquito

In India many of the people are hugely affected by [Chikungunya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chikungunya) disease and doctors couldn't wipe out this disease here. In our locality almost every household has some Chikungunya patients.

Is there any complete cure of this disease. Are there effective do's and don'ts recommended?

Comment: Welcome to HealthSE! I've edited your question to help others better understand the situation and the disease you are talking about. If you think that changed it too much or if there are still information missing, please edit it yourself. Nice question. You're invited to take the [tour](https://health.stackexchange.com/tour) and read the [help](https://health.stackexchange.com/help) as well.

Comment: I am happy with the edit :))..

Answer (score 3):

Since 'the cure' or rather a vaccine against the virus is still only on the horizon, affected populations have to resort to prevention measures and supportive care, once the infection breaks out. Even with a vaccine, [mosquito population control](http://whqlibdoc.who.int/publications/1982/9241700661_eng.pdf) and bite prevention will be necessary to control chikungunya disease.

[Chikungunya at the Door — Déjà Vu All Over Again](http://www.nejm.org/doi/10.1056/NEJMp1408509)

> We now face a new threat posed by the unrelated chikungunya virus, which causes a disease clinically similar to dengue in a similar epidemiologic pattern, which is transmitted by the same mosquito vectors, and for which we also lack vaccines and specific treatments. […] Thus, the current chikungunya threat to the United States must be met primarily with standard public health approaches such as mosquito control and avoidance. In addition, there is an important role for astute clinicians in diagnosing and reporting the disease when it occurs.

The Do's include limiting the habitat and reach of the mosquitos. 
If possible any open [still waters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stagnant_water) should be [drained](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC149385/), [closed](http://www.who.int/denguecontrol/control_strategies/en/) or [covered](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK143163/). Uneven spots of ground where puddles are forming after a rain should be filled with earth or other material. Wholes in a road should be fixed as soon as possible.

Tightly woven [screens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_screen) in front of doors and windows might help to keep the insects out of homes, [nets](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0001706X09001910) around beds to keep those already in away from sleeping humans. Wearing long clothes helps to prevent the incidents of bites.

Insect [repellent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insect_repellent) chemicals like [DEET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DEET), [p-Menthane-3,8-diol](https://doi.org/10.2987%2F8756-971X%282006%2922%5B507%3APARBMR%5D2.0.CO%3B2) or [Icaridin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Icaridin) applied to the exposed skin, clothing and even parts of a house structure might help to keep them away. If those strong chemicals arr either not available, not affordable or not well tolerated by the people who should apply them, much weaker [natural repellents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insect_repellent#Common_natural_insect_repellents) might be worth a try.

Since the disease vector is an insect, very [targeted](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2925229/) and limited usage of pesticides might be an option to consider. This is an option that has rather wide spread consequences beyond just [killing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_pest_management) the mosquitos and those might develop resistance or already are [resistant](http://journals.plos.org/plosntds/article?id=10.1371/journal.pntd.0005054) to the chemicals to employed there. Most of those insecticides are not really safe for humans to use and the actual way they are used (misused, misapplied, over-dosed, under-dosed etc.) might have a net effect that's undesirable.

A more humane and less environmental destructive method of [limiting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insect_trap) the number of mosquitos is to [trap](https://youtu.be/VAT3Kq_w_VM) them. Their are two ways in principle to achieve this: either sexual stimulation with pheromones, leading the insects to sticky traps from where they do not escape. Or exploiting their [target acquisition](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rovuyeXl42Y) system, by presenting them [decoy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pNjyLRQutXs) signals that will steer a significant number of them away from humans and animals and into the traps.

Since a significant number of infections result from bites of the insects while being outside, long clothing, repellents should be among the first things to do for individuals. A number of larger scale fan traps might be worth to try in a community effort to decrease the spread of the insects and reduce the number of bites for people being outside.

Although it is about the similar disease called Dengue fever, this guide:
[Vector Management and Delivery of Vector Control Services](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK143163/) –  and others like it – should be read  and everything in there that an individual can do should be put into action and tried as soon as possible. If any aspect in there is of a size too large for individuals these components should be addressed by the local community and even escalated to higher authorities.

Answer (score 2):

The only effective management of viruses is by vaccination. In this way diseases such as measles have been eradicated from some countries.

Currently there is no vaccine available so ecological measures such as controlling the mosquito vector need to be employed.

Vaccines are under development eg. http://www.nature.com/nm/journal/v23/n2/full/nm.4253.html

Answer (score -2):

Your probably meant this:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gene_drive

A relatively new technology where a specially structured gene sequence is added to a species in such a way that it encourages the spread of the sequence through the population. This includes malicious sequences designed to extinct or near-extinct a species. Gene drives work best in quickly-reproducing species, making them perfect for eradicating pest species that spread dangerous diseases.

The 2 most obvious pest species to eradicate (providing the most benefit per cost): mosquitoes and rats.

Comment: Once again dishonest, terrible, failing downvotes with no comment or explanation. Obviously downvoted by an offended rat or mosquito. #FakeDownvotes!

Comment: I wasn't the downvoter but I easily could have been. I might have downvoted not because I think you're wrong. It's a fascinating concept that has obvious potential (and obvious risks). If you had explained it more plainly, in your own words instead of just a link, and used a better source of support than wikipedia then I would have upvoted instead of thinking about downvoting. I suspect the downvoter thought the same.

Comment: I downvoted for the reasons @CareyGregory gave.

Comment: Although I also do not agree that such a radical approach (eradicate a few species, easypeasy, sure why not?) for a possible future solution (does yours even apply to mosquitoes and rats? how? explain!) with unforeseen consequences will be the best answer for an immediate problem – it might be a valid answer nevertheless. Note that if you edit your answer, perhaps guided by the hints Carey gave, you might improve the answer but perhaps also *reverse* a couple of downvotes or gain upvotes in turn.